# How to access the object in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, object

```
TEXT_TO_READ = """{

    "tts_type": "text",

    "tts_input": "I am Hungry"

}"""
```

my old code :

```
scriptPath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
scriptPath = os.path.dirname(scriptPath)
line = os.path.join(scriptPath, "input.txt")
TEXT_TO_READ["tts_input"] = line
```

I am trying to access the tts_input of TEXT_TO_READ. but I think, I am making a mistake. can some one help me , how to access this ?

I am not able to read the 4 line of my code and getting the error as :    TEXT_TO_READ[tts_input] = line
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tts_input'. can someone help me ?

Comment: Your code does not generate that error message.

Comment: Please put back the original code, so that the context of the answer is understandable. If you want to show how you've modified the code and ask followon questions, append it to the question instead of replacing.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse `TEXT_TO_READ` into an object. You can use python library *json* to achieve that.

```
import json
TEXT_TO_READ = """{"tts_type": "text","tts_input": "I am Hungry"}"""
TEXT_TO_READ = json.loads(TEXT_TO_READ)
# rest of the code
TEXT_TO_READ["tts_input"] = line
```

Of course, if the `TEXT_TO_READ` string is defined in the code (not pulled from the database or whatever, use modification @Deleisha suggested).
However if you need to have it as string, json.loads() will parse it into an object.

## UPDATE

Since you have another bug in updated question, I'll update my answer.
In your new code, you have

```
TEXT_TO_READ1 = json.loads(TEXT_TO_READ)
```

and later

```
TEXT_TO_READ["tts_input"] = line
```

What you did is saved object into TEXT_TO_READ**1** and again tried to pull "tts_input" property from the string. Please, modify it to `TEXT_TO_READ1["tts_input"] = line`

## UPDATE 2

Ok, so, if I understand your code correctly, Request.add_json_parameter() should accept STRING as `data` argument. In the assignment `TEXT_TO_READ["tts_input"] = line` you only wanted to update the original string. After that you should convert it back to string again, with json.dumps()

Therefore, after this line

```
TEXT_TO_READ["tts_input"] = line
```

add

```
TEXT_TO_READ = json.dumps(TEXT_TO_READ)
```

## UPDATE 3 (as an answer to comment)

You have to change

```
line = os.path.join(scriptPath, "input.txt")
TEXT_TO_READ["tts_input"] = line
```

to this

```
line = os.path.join(scriptPath, "input.txt")
TEXT_TO_READ["tts_input"] = open(line, "r").read()
```

in order to actually read contents of the file.

Comment: I modified my code as above. But I am getting the error as : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tts.py", line 213, in <module>
    body, boundary = request.encode()
  File ".\tts.py", line 98, in encode
    body.write(parameter.encode())
  File ".\tts.py", line 54, in encode
    body.write(self.data)
TypeError: 'dict' does not have the buffer interface

Comment: @sam: that is different (although possibly related) error, it's not in the code you had shown us.

Comment: I modified my code as above- getting the error as - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tts.py", line 191, in <module>
    TEXT_TO_READ["tts_input"] = line
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: @sam You need to use `TEXT_TO_READ1` there.

Comment: Updated my answer. @Barmar, yes. Hopefully it was just a typo

Comment: @kecer He edited the question after you posted the answer.

Comment: I updated the complete code . I am getting the error as : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tts.py", line 213, in <module>
    body, boundary = request.encode()
  File ".\tts.py", line 98, in encode
    body.write(parameter.encode())
  File ".\tts.py", line 54, in encode
    body.write(self.data)
TypeError: 'dict' does not have the buffer interface

Comment: again the errror : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tts.py", line 213, in <module>
    body, boundary = request.encode()
  File ".\tts.py", line 98, in encode
    body.write(parameter.encode())
  File ".\tts.py", line 54, in encode
    body.write(self.data)
TypeError: 'dict' does not have the buffer interface

Comment: @sam I misread the code, read the updated answer now.

Comment: last question : it is taking input as a path but not the content of input.txt file. how to solve this ?

Comment: thanks. Last question : I have updated my code with the response, I want to write the text part in to a file and the binary to .pcm file, how can I do that ? I am getting the response, which is a mixture of text and binary. please help

Comment: Please stop asking vampire questions: if you have any questions am that are only tangentially related to your original question, **ask a new one**.

Comment: Thanks @Terry, just wanted to point out this is getting out of hand.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to access string. Make the following change

```
TEXT_TO_READ = {
    "tts_type": "text",
    "tts_input": "I am Hungry"
}
```

Comment: I cant change that. it is a reply from the server. Can you please tell me how to access the string ?

Comment: Oh, In that case you need to use `json.loads()` function as answered by @kecer

Comment: I updated my complete code. I am getting the error as : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tts.py", line 213, in <module>
    body, boundary = request.encode()
  File ".\tts.py", line 98, in encode
    body.write(parameter.encode())
  File ".\tts.py", line 54, in encode
    body.write(self.data)
TypeError: 'dict' does not have the buffer interface